# Kohana auth model

Tags: kohana

I'm new to kohana 3.2 and i couldnt find any answer regrading the auth module.
this is my code and forsome reason ever since i changed the user model to extend model_auth_user
the validation isnt being done prooperly. The password field can be inserted empty and no excpetion will be caught and same if the password_confirm and password fields are different:

```
       public function action_new()
        {
        if ($_POST){
      try
               {
        $user = ORM::factory('user')
        ->values(array(
           'username' => $_POST['username'],
           'email' => $_POST['email'],
               'password' => $_POST['password'],
           'password_confirm' => $_POST['password_confirm']));

        $user->save();
        $user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')));
        $this->request->redirect('user/index'); 
      } 
      catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) 
      {
            $errors = $e->errors();
      }    
}

    $view = View::factory('user/new') 
    ->bind('errors',$errors);      //pass the info to the view
    $this->response->body($view);  //show the view
     }
```

thanks

Comment: Show Model_User code please. Check it for correct `rules()` method.

Comment: The rules for the password can't be created via `rules()` because then it will already be hashed. You need to check (and post) `create_user` from `Model_Auth_User` (or the class you use that extends Model_Auth_User)

Comment: Use Kohana 3.3. In your case you'd probably redefined some of the original `Model_Auth_User` methods or properties and hadn't incuded parent function or propery code.

Answer (score 0):

You can override run_filter() method to force Kohana ignore password filtering in case of empty value. For example, put this code to your User_Model:

```
protected function run_filter($field, $value)
{
  if ($field === "password" AND $value === "")
    return "";
  parent::run_filter($field, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code sample from Model_Auth_User::create_user();

```
$user->save(Model_User::get_password_validation($_POST)->rule('password', 'not_empty'));
```

This validation execute before filters(hashing password). After hashing - blank password becomes not empty string.